# Issue with Input TLF textfield in Flash as3 Adobe Air

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

Input  TLF textfield  having issue while player inputting text  in mobile.
When player focus into the TLF textfield,then mobile keyboard is opened.But when one start to enter text ,then TLF not getting any inputted character.
That means Input TLF not working as Input,its working only as dynamic TLF in mobile version.

To fix this issue,Adobe introduced "StageText" for only Mobile version.
StageText is perfect for mobile devices but it support all features of TLF textfield except RTL direction..

can anyone tell me whether its fixed or not?

Comment: TLF Text was removed from Flash CC, I wouldn't expect it to be fully supported..

Answer (score 0):

If you are develop for iOS, then use FPTextField of the  FPNativeUI.ane:

```
var textField:FPTextField = new FPTextField();
textField.frame = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 20);
textField.textAlignment = FPTextAlignment.RIGHT;
textField.setWritingDirection(FPTextWritingDirection.RTL);
textField.stage.addChild(textField);
```

Download ane: https://github.com/flashpress/FPNativeUI-ANE .
Compare StageText vs FPTextField: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKYaoLtEmCU